# PHP Script updates all users value rather than individual user value

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I’m pretty much a complete beginner when it comes to PHP and have been having some problems with updating the values in the database – when the script fires it updates every users value in the column rather than just the individual who is logged in.

Some background info:

Database name: “user”

Table “users” with columns User ID , Username , Password , Emailaddress , Offer.

Site that I’m working on allows users to complete a number of offers and then get rewarded upon completion. The offer column has the default value of “1” and Upon login the user is redirected according to the value in the offer column. (So on first login user is redirected to example.com/offer1 , after offer 1 is completed this value is updated so on next login user is redirected to example.com/offer2 – in essence storing the users progress)

This is the script which is played after an offer is completed (in this case after offer 3 is completed) – aim to connect to database and then update that users “offer value” so when they next login they will be directed to the correct offer – thus storing their progress:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","name","pass","user");
$select = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT offer FROM users      WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"));
$plus = $select['offer']++;
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=3".$plus);
header("location: http://example.com/offer4".$plus);
?>
```

This does work in updating the values but does so for *all users* in the database rather than just the one user who is logged in. So lets say Jim has completed this offer , his Offer value will be updates to 3 but so will all the other users will have their offer value set to 3 when only Jim’s should be. – hope that this makes sense.  How could I change the above script so only the logged in users value gets set. Maybe it’s a problem with sessions ? or this part of the script isn't working

`$select = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT offer FROM users      WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"));`

Just in case it helps , This is part of the login script which redirects depending on the value in the users offer column which works fine.

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />';
```

So for default value of 1 user redirected to example.com/offer1 etc.

Heres also my full login script in case its needed:

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="main">
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

     $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

         echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />'; 

    }
    else
    {
         echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
    }
}
else
{
    ?>

   <h1>Member Login</h1>

   <p>Thanks for visiting! Please either login below, or <a href="register.php">click here to register</a>.</p>

    <form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

   <?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly, heres base.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$dbhost = "localhost"; // this will ususally be 'localhost', but can sometimes differ
$dbname = "user"; // the name of the database that you are going to use for this project
$dbuser = "name"; // the username that you created, or were given, to access your database
$dbpass = "password"; // the password that you created, or were given, to access your database

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: `update foo set bar = 3 WHERE`. Use WHERE! to determine user you want to update. [Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm)

Answer (score 2):

you must specify a where condition

Change the below code

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=3".$plus);
```

to

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=3".$plus."where Username  = $_SESSION['username']" );
```

Unless the where condition is given update will be applied to all the records in the table

Comment: Thanks @Vijayaragavendran , for some reason i'm getting a Syntax error though when I replace the code. Can't seem to be able to correct it.

Comment: Just theres a syntax error on line 6- heres the full code (thanks for the help though!) <?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pass","user");
$select = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT offer FROM user      WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"));
$plus = $select['offer']++;
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=3".$plus."where user_id" = $id);
header("location: http://example.com/offer4".$plus);
?>

Comment: Okay , so thats solved the Syntax which is great. Just now isn't updating the offer value at all :( (i.e. remaining on 1 after script is run) Could this be a problem with the login script not starting the session correctly?  Again , thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does not seem to be PHP, but SQL...

Repalce:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=3".$plus);
```

with:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=".$plus." WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Comment: Thanks @Sérgio Bernardo ; tried swapping this and now it isn't updating the value in the database at all.

Comment: Probably some SQL error... place this code after que UPDATE query to see the error in the mySQL server:

print "Mysql error: ".mysqli_error();